# RDS PostgreSQL - too may connections for database "db_name"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm getting too many connections for database error. But there's only 6 active connections to the entire `Postgres RDS Server`.

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 53300: too many connections for
> database "db_name"

```
Max Connections: 300
Active Connections: 6
```

`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'dbname';` is getting empty

Comment: These are the active connections only. Is it possible you have idle connections as well which are not being terminated? Can you find all the connections to the db?

Comment: What is the max connections for db_name?  There are 7 integers between 0 and 6 inclusive.....

Comment: @jjanes how to check max connections for a specific db alone?

Comment: The table pg_database has a column datconnlimit.  -1 means "unlimited".  You will need to be able to connect to some other database on the same server in order to query this table though.

Comment: @jjanes datconnlimit shows as 10 so that seems to be the bottleneck here ? I cannot directly update it on rds to a higher number. I don't have any pooler yet.